# Pyhton extract matrices from rank 3 tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix, tensor

I have data `X_train` with shape `(19601, 1000, 12)` but want to extract the 1000 x 12 matrices and combine/append them into one large matrix. Whenever I try to index through `X_train` and append the rows of the matrices into one large matrix, I get the undesired shape. I want a matrix of shape `(12*19601, 1000)`. I tried a list comprehension and played with the indices `i,j,k`:

`data = [sig[i][j][k] for sig in X_train]`

but got nowhere. I think I am misunderstanding something. What can I do to get a matrix of size `(12*19601, 1000)`?

Answer (score 1):

transpose (19601, 1000, 12) to (12,19691,1000) and then reshape

```
temp = arr.transpose(2,0,1)
temp1 = temp.reshape(12*19691,1000)
```

Comment: It threw the error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 235212000 into shape (236292,1000)`

Comment: double check for typos.  I see a 235 and 236

Comment: yep it was a typo! it should be 19601, thanks